# How to pass parameters to a constructor through an interface in PHP

Tags: php

Im using an interface to interact with a class and its methods.  How can I pass parameters (user credentials) to the constructor in this class? Ive only managed to make it work by hard coding some parameters in the "Wrapper".  Then calling the methods works as it should.

```
namespace App\Http;

interface WrapperInterface
{
    public function __construct(string $id, $secret);
}


class Wrapper implements WrapperInterface
{
    public function __construct($id = '', $secret = '')
    {
        $this->id = $id;
        $this->secret = $secret;

        $this->curlInit();
    }

    public function SomeFunction()
    {
        // some functionality

        return $this->SomePrivateFunction();

    }

    private function SomePrivateFunction()
    {
        // some functionality
    }
}
```

```
use App\Http\WrapperInterface;


class SomeCommand 
{
    private $client
    public function __construct(WrapperInterface $client)
    {
        $this->client = $client;
        parent::__construct();
    }

    public function handle()
    {
        $this->client->someFunction();
    }
}
```

Comment: First, this shouldn't compile car you don't extend an interface, you implement it (`implements`). Second, having a constructor signature in an interface is probably not a good idea (an interface should define *what objects will be able to do*, not *how objects should be Instantiated*). Third, I'm not exactly sure what you're trying to accomplish. But here you can instantiate a `Wrapper` with the credentials then pass it over to your command?

Comment: @Jeto woops! it was my mistake when posting the question.  i have "implements" in my code, sorry.  Just want to know whats the best way to pass parameters when instantiating the Wrapper class.

Answer (score 0):

All of your code is syntactically incorrect.

1. Classes don't `extend` interfaces, they `implement` them.
2. Classes must implement interface method prototypes *exactly*.
3. Class `SomeCommand` has no parent, so you can't call `parent::anything` unless you truly want the generic `Object` class's blank methods/properties.
4. I've never seen a constructor defined in an interface and it's probably not a good idea, but it doesn't seem to be forbidden, so... fill your boots.

It *looks* like you want to do composition, which would look like:

```
interface WrapperInterface {
    public function __construct(string $id, $secret);
}

class Wrapper implements WrapperInterface {
    protected $id, $secret;

    public function __construct(string $id, $secret) {
        $this->id = $id;
        $this->secret = $secret;
    }

    public function debug() {
        return [ $this->id, $this->secret ];
    }
}

class SomeCommand {
    private $client;

    public function __construct(WrapperInterface $client) {
        $this->client = $client;
    }

    public function debug() {
        return $this->client->debug();
    }
}

$i = new Wrapper('someid', 'somesecret');
$c = new SomeCommand($i);

var_dump( $c->debug() );
```

and is actual, runnable code: https://3v4l.org/9L2Uo

Comment: sorry it was my mistake when posting the question, i have "implements" in my actual code, sorry.  so there's no point in using an interface for this? I did know how to instantiate the class by itself without the interface.. but oh well.. thanks anyway!